# Почему не работает ввод с акселерометра

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Суть проблемы в том что я написал простейшую игру и в ней работает всё кроме управления, а именно игра не считывает показатели акселерометра
Ниже прикладываю скрипт

```
void fixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            horizontal = Input.acceleration.x;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.x < 0)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
        }
        if (Input.acceleration.x > 0)
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
        }
        DoodleRigid.velocity = new Vector2(Input.acceleration.x * 10f, DoodleRigid.velocity.y);
    }
```

Comment: Вы уверенны, что не считываются именно показатели акселерометра - этого быть не может. Дебагайте какое значение у вас получается

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer Могу скинуть полностью скрипт, если это поможет решить проблему